# javascript selecting style tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coding-style

I thought that you could select a style element by doing:

```
<style id="mystyle"></style>
```

And then

```
$('#mystyle').remove()
```

But no go. How do I select the style in js?

Thanks.

Comment: This should work...style tag is removed for me.. are you expecting styles generated from within that style tag to be removed? Because I don't think it works that way.. example: you have a dive that points to a class within that style tag, and it is styled based on the class rules...and then you go back and remove that style tag...I'm pretty sure the div's markup will be preserved...

Comment: @Crayon: CSS is not preserved when the Style is removed from the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

`$('style[id=mystyle]').remove()`

Answer (score 3):

The style element can't have an `id` attribute, according to the spec.

```
<!ELEMENT STYLE - - %StyleSheet        -- style info -->
<!ATTLIST STYLE
  %i18n;                               -- lang, dir, for use with title --
  type        %ContentType;  #REQUIRED -- content type of style language --
  media       %MediaDesc;    #IMPLIED  -- designed for use with these media --
  title       %Text;         #IMPLIED  -- advisory title --
  >
```

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3).

However, in practice, browsers generally let you get away with these things. Their implementations may be different though.

Have you considered selecting it via another means? What about `$('head style:eq(1))`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine in Firefox 4.x ...

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tv2qF/1/)**

```
$('#mystyle1').remove();

$('style[id=mystyle2]').remove();

document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('mystyle3'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this workaround?

```
$("head").find("#mystyle")
```

Or alternatively, go back to basics and use old school javascript:

```
document.getElementById("mystyle")
```